# Использование скрипта в качестве индексного файла

Tags: javascript, gulp, browsersync

Приветствую.

Пытаюсь подружить `Gulp` и [`BrowserSync`](https://www.browsersync.io).
С `HTML` всё отлично, но в проекте нет `HTML`, только `JS`.
Но с `JS` никак не работает, переход на скрипт из-под запущенного сервера выдаст код скрипта (в верным MIME) и **без** обновления в браузере.

На одном из десятков сайтов, где я искал решение, было сказано что для обновления необходим тег `<body></body>`, чтобы подключить скрипты для синхронизации.

Итого 2 вопроса:

1. Как заставить BrowserSync оперативно обновлять в браузере скрипты/стили?
2. Как скрипт выполнить без `HTML`?

Решение, на мой взгляд, довольно простое: оборачивать скрипты в разметку неявно.
Сейчас используется костыль в виде совершенно лишнего `HTML`-файла, к которому подключен скрипт.
Это слегка омрачает полное удовлетворение хорошим продуктом.

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Очень давно работаю в этой связке и много чего приходилось настраивать в `bs`, вплоть до роуторов и все это с реактом и ему подобными, но даже самые порнографические мысли не могут привести хотя бы к одному ответу - зачем это надо? И если браузер ожидает `html`, разве он в состоянии выполнить `js`?

Comment: @OlmerDale, Вот поэтому я и считаю что нужна обёртка. Скрипт сам генерирует HTML-код для отображения.

Comment: [Gulp 7: Автоперезагрузка браузера: browser-sync](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiMJNIG-yvg) с 4:30 до 5:40 наверно ваш случай

Comment: @greybutton, хорошая попытка, но нет. Просто есть возможность самому вставить отслеживающий скрипт, что меня никак не спасает, т. к. вставляется он тоже в `HTML`, которого у меня нет.

Comment: что именно открывается в браузере?

Comment: @Grundy, собирается в `bundle.js`. Больше нет файлов.

Comment: @Other, а в браузере-то что открывается?

Comment: @Grundy, в вопросе описано: "выдаст код скрипта (в верным MIME) и без обновления в браузере".

Comment: верный mime это какой?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47561/discussion-between-other-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось перехватом запроса к скриптам с помощью `middleware` и оборачивать их в `HTML` (решение не допилено напильником ещё, так что не судите строго):

```
browserSync.init({
    // ...
    middleware: function(req, res, next){
      // Если это скрипт
      if(req.url === '/'){
        res.end("<html><head><title>Browser Sync</title></head><body><script src='/" + data.js.buildName + "'></script></html>"); 
      }else{ 
        next(); 
      } 
    }
    // ...
});
```

Спасибо пользователю @IvanPetrov за идею в чате.